# redirect_uri_mismatch without reason

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth

i have error 404 bad request but I added well in  dashboard google

> redirect_uri check image for see.
> {
> "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
> "error_description": "Bad Request"
> }

[image]

thank for you help.

Answer (score 0):

> redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect uri you have added in Google developer console must **exactly** match the one that your application is sending from.  There should be additional details you can see as to where your request is coming from.

Check the error message being returned it will tell you exactly what redirect uri you are sending.  Check the: The protocol and ports must exactly match also check that there is or is not a trailing space or slash.

Comment: I tried to write all the urls possible and to have been careful ... it does not want.
the only "solution" that I found... is to use the word postmessage ....

Comment: You need to check the message coming back from Google it will tell you the exact URI that you are sending as the redirect URI.   Dont guess just check the message and ad that.

Answer (score 0):

For all the people who may see this just building on @DalmTo 's answer:

**MAKE SURE BOTH ARE HTTP OR HTTPS**
This had left me befuddled for quite a while

NOTE:
Does not answer OP